# Finding number of nodes within a certain distance in a rooted tree

Tags: algorithm

In a rooted and weighted tree, how can you find the number of nodes within a certain distance from each node? You only need to consider down edges, e.g. nodes going down from the root. Keep in mind each edge has a weight.

I can do this  in `O(N^2)` time using a DFS from each node and keeping track of the distance traveled, but with `N >= 100000` it's a bit slow. I'm pretty sure you could easily solve it with unweighted edges with DP, but anyone know how to solve this one quickly? (Less than `N^2`)

Comment: One possible idea (for nonnegative weights) is to compute a heap for each node (bottom up), popping off values which exceed the maximum distance. I think using binomial heaps here would work (with minor changes) for O(n log n) time.

Comment: @Nabb how do you merge 2 max-heaps.

Comment: @Topro: That's why I suggested using binomial heaps, for which we can merge two heaps in O(log n).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to improve my previous answer to **O(nlog d) time** and O(n) space by making use of the following observation:

> The number of sufficiently-close nodes at a given node v is the sum of the numbers of sufficiently-close nodes of each of its children, less the number of nodes that have *just become* insufficiently-close.

Let's call the distance threshold m, and the distance on the edge between two adjacent nodes u and v d(u, v).

### Every node has a single ancestor that is the first ancestor to miss out

For each node v, we will maintain a count, c(v), that is initially 0.

For any node v, consider the chain of ancestors from v's parent up to the root.  Call the ith node in this chain a(v, i).  Notice that v needs to be counted as sufficiently close in some number i >= 0 of the first nodes in this chain, and in no other nodes.  If we are able to quickly find i, then we can simply *decrement* c(a(v, i+1)) (bringing it (possibly further) below 0), so that when the counts of a(v, i+1)'s children are added to it in a later pass, v is correctly excluded from being counted.  Provided we calculate fully accurate counts for all children of a node v before adding them to c(v), any such exclusions are correctly "propagated" to parent counts.

The tricky part is finding i efficiently.  Call the sum of the distances of the first j >= 0 edges on the path from v to the root s(v, j), and call the list of all depth(v)+1 of these path lengths, listed in increasing order, s(v).  What we want to do is binary-search the list of path lengths s(v) for the first entry greater than the threshold m: this would find i+1 in log(d) time.  The problem is constructing s(v).  We could easily build it using a running total from v up to the root -- but that would require O(d) time per node, nullifying any time improvement.  We need a way to construct s(v) from s(parent(v)) in constant time, but the problem is that as we recurse from a node v to its child u, the path lengths grow "the wrong way": every path length x needs to become x + d(u, v), and a new path length of 0 needs to be added at the beginning.  This appears to require O(d) updates, but a trick gets around the problem...

### Finding i quickly

The solution is to calculate, at each node v, the total path length t(v) of all edges on the path from v to the root.  This is easily done in constant time per node: t(v) = t(parent(v)) + d(v, parent(v)).  We can then form s(v) by prepending -t to the beginning of s(parent(v)), and when performing the binary search, consider each element s(v, j) to represent s(v, j) + t (or equivalently, binary search for m - t instead of m).  The insertion of -t at the start can be achieved in O(1) time by having a child u of a node v share v's path length array, with s(u) considered to begin one memory location before s(v).  All path length arrays are "right-justified" inside a single memory buffer of size d+1 -- specifically, nodes at depth k will have their path length array begin at offset d-k inside the buffer to allow room for their descendant nodes to prepend entries.  The array sharing means that sibling nodes will overwrite each other's path lengths, but this is not a problem: we only need the values in s(v) to remain valid while v and v's descendants are processed in the preorder DFS.

In this way we gain the *effect* of O(d) path length increases in O(1) time.  Thus the total time required to find i at a given node is O(1) (to build s(v)) plus O(log d) (to find i using the modified binary search) = O(log d).  A single preorder DFS pass is used to find and decrement the appropriate ancestor's count for each node; a postorder DFS pass then sums child counts into parent counts.  These two passes can be combined into a single pass over the nodes that performs operations both before and after recursing.

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT: Please see my other answer for an even more efficient O(nlog d) solution :) ]**

Here's a simple O(nd)-time, O(n)-space algorithm, where d is the maximum depth of any node in the tree.  A complete tree (a tree in which every node has the same number of children) with n nodes has depth d = O(log n), so this should be much faster than your O(n^2) DFS-based approach in most cases, though if the number of sufficiently-close descendants per node is small (i.e. if DFS only traverses a small number of levels) then your algorithm should not be too bad either.

For any node v, consider the chain of ancestors from v's parent up to the root.  Notice that v needs to be counted as sufficiently close in some number i >= 0 of the first nodes in this chain, and in no other nodes.  So all we need to do is **for each node, climb upwards towards the root until such time as the total path length exceeds the threshold distance m, incrementing the count at each ancestor as we go.**  There are n nodes, and for each node there are at most d ancestors, so this algorithm is trivially O(nd).

Comment: does it require upward links?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes. If these aren't already present in the tree node structure, they can be found in O(n) time using a single DFS pass, and stored either inside a field in each tree node or all together in a separate n-element array, whichever is convenient.